# relays interfering each other

Tags: relay, interference

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f74s4W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi: I have 3 relays (230V coil, 2 contacts) in a system, all the coils 'returns' are wired together, while hots come from the various controllers.

Now: only 1 of the 3 relays stays on at a time, even though all coils are powered. And if the fist and/or the second is on and third comes up, the first and the second suddently goes off
NOTE: ! stands for 'off'

so:

```
INPUT           OUTPUT
R1   R2   R3 -> L1  !L2 !L3
R1   R2  !R3 -> L1  !L2 !L3
R1  !R2  !R3 -> L1  !L2 !L3
!R1 !R2  !R3 -> !L1 !L2 !L3
!R1  R2   R3 -> !L1  L2 !L3
!R1  R2   !R3 -> !L1 L2 !L3
!R1  !R2   R3 -> !L1 !L2 L3
R1   !R2   R3 -> L1  !L2 !L3
```

Schema edited to be more 'accurate'

Picture of thr 'actual' circuit:
[image: Circuit]
Black wires is '0-V dry contact', white cables are mostly live (but one that is 'common' neutral: left-most red labeled)

EDIT:
Tried with multimetre and found some strange situations. In some circumstance I found too little drop across a coil ex: control and control1 are on, i found 220V across Rly2 and 0,05V across Rly1 (wich I taught should be the same 220V) [0,7V across Rly3 that is fine].

Another strange situation:
all switches on, found 220V across RLY2, 0,5V across RLY1 and RLY3. Other cases are fine.

Comment: How common is the common?

Comment: Show us a diagram of exactly what is connected where...

Comment: Show Cascaded loads and remote voltage drop across coil.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rearrange your table.

```
INPUT             OUTPUT               Notes
!R1  !R2  !R3 -> !L1  !L2 !L3     (4)  All off.

 R1  !R2  !R3 ->  L1  !L2 !L3     (3)  L1 on.
 R1   R2  !R3 ->  L1  !L2 !L3     (2)  L1 on.
 R1  !R2   R3 ->  L1  !L2 !L3     (8)  L1 on.
 R1   R2   R3 ->  L1  !L2 !L3     (1)  L1 on.

!R1   R2  !R3 -> !L1   L2 !L3     (6)  L2 on.
!R1   R2   R3 -> !L1   L2 !L3     (5)  L2 on.

!R1  !R2   R3 -> !L1  !L2  L3     (7)  L3 on.
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff9CxO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A more 'accurate' circuit?*

Comment: No: I havn't any connection between the 'controlled' circuits, only common is the 'neutral' shared among the coils (and actually a second load shared between)

Comment: So, you are saying that one or two of the relays will not pick up even if there is 230 V on the coil? (Did you measure the coil voltage?) I think you should add a photo of the wiring.

Comment: Exact: as soon as R1 goes in, others go out. And as soon as R1 goes out, R2 (or) R3 go in. This results in the 'shared' load always behaving 'as it's supposed to do' but the 'individual' loads not working as predicted.

Comment: I didn't measure the voltage directly, I used a test-light. It lit on both sides of the coils when only R1 was on

Comment: (1) What do you mean by a test light? One probe or two probes? (2) It lit on both sides of *which* coils when only R1 was on. (Can you see how confusing your comments are?) Where's the photo?

Comment: Test-light is what we call literally hot-finder. I 'touch' the top (closing the circuit to ground) so if the tip is on a hot wire the bulb lit.

Comment: Also Load and load2 now arn't connected because of this issue (only the 'controlled appliance' and and Load1 are actually in use )

Comment: You have N connected to A2 on left relay and A1 on the other two. This might work but it shows lack of care in wiring so there may be other problems. Your hot-finder will pick up stray voltages too easily. A multimeter or 2-probe tester would be better.

Comment: I'll try with a multimeter.

Comment: Tried with multimetre and found some strange situations

Comment: @DDS - I'll bet you do. While your picture is not real helpful, it looks like the black comes down from off-camera, then connects to the common of the middle relay, and I don't see any other connections from there. Then another black looks like it connects from the middle left contact to common of the left hand relay.

Answer (score 0):

All relays have a wide range of hysteresis with specs give as;

- Turn On Voltage (Max).....    Turn Off Voltage (Min)... or in other words
- MUST turn ON before  ..... MUST turn OFF above
- > 50%~75% Vnom .........  10%~40%   of Vnom  ( depends on design)

Therefore for any of your relays to be misbehaving due to other relays or loads sharing a common 230Vac line, implies faulty wiring somewhere.

Comment: My relays are Finder 405282300000, keeping voltage: 80%, release voltage: 20%, turn on voltage: 110% to 80%. Now I'll test which voltages I have across the coils. I think coils have really low resistence so the voltage is 'passing trough' not letting the following relay to see enough voltage drop

Comment: I hope the coils are not wired in series. That could cause a problem

Comment: No, those are not in series.

Comment: If your load dips the voltage well below 80% then you may have a power quality issue.